# Should I use Int32 for small number instead of Int or Int64 in 64 bit architecture

Tags: ios, swift, cpu-architecture

The iOS app I am working on supports only 64-bit devices. 
When creating new `Int` type in swift and considering the fact that the range that I want to store will never overflow `Int32`, I wonder if there is any benefit of using `Int32` instead or `Int`/`Int64`.

Comment: Probably not, but you won't know without profiling it. The Swift convention is to use `Int` as a the common currency type for integers, even in cases where it's not strictly needed. For example, `Array.count` is `Int`, even though it'll never need to be negative, and probably will never need to be greater than `Int32.max`. This alleviates the need for conversions all over the place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, use Int. The [Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html) is quite explicit about this:

> Unless you need to work with a specific size of integer, always use Int for integer values in your code. This aids code consistency and interoperability. Even on 32-bit platforms, Int can store any value between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647, and is large enough for many integer ranges.

By "work with a specific size of integer," the documentation is describing situations such as file formats and networking protocols that are defined in terms of specific bit-widths. Even if you're only counting to 10, you should still store it in an Int.

Int types do not automatically convert, so if you have an Int32, and a function requires an Int, you'd have to convert it as `Int(x)`. This gets very cumbersome very quickly. To avoid that, Swift strongly recommends everything be an Int unless you have a specific reason to do otherwise.

You should also avoid UInt, even if your value is unsigned. You should only use UInt when you mean "this machine-word-sized bit pattern" and you should only use the sized UInts (UInt32, etc) when you mean "this bit-width bit pattern." If you mean "a number" (even an unsigned number), you should use Int.

> Use UInt only when you specifically need an unsigned integer type with the same size as the platform’s native word size. If this isn’t the case, Int is preferred, even when the values to be stored are known to be nonnegative. A consistent use of Int for integer values aids code interoperability, avoids the need to convert between different number types, and matches integer type inference, as described in Type Safety and Type Inference.

---

See Peter's comments below for some links to further discussion on performance. It is very true that using 32-bit integers can be a significant performance improvement when working with large data structures, particularly because of caching and locality issues. But as a rule, this should be hidden within a data type that manages that extra complexity, isolating performance-critical code from the main system. Shifting back and forth between 32- and 64-bit integers can easily overwhelm the advantages of smaller data if you're not careful.

So as a rule, use Int. There are advantages to using Int32 in some cases, but trying to use it as a default is as likely to hurt performance as help it, and will definitely increase code complexity dramatically.

Comment: @LeoDabus Fair; though the term Swift uses (and rightly I think) is "convert."

Comment: What size is Int on x86-64?  Arrays of 32-bit integers take only half the cache footprint / memory bandwidth of 64-bit integers, and on some CPUs some 32-bit operations are faster than corresponding 64-bit.  (e.g. integer division on Intel CPUs is like 2.5x faster for the same values by using 32-bit division.)  [The advantages of using 32bit registers/instructions in x86-64](//stackoverflow.com/q/38303333) - also points out the machine-code size advantage.

Comment: The performance advantages probably don't outweigh convenience of not casting for most code, but this only answers the "should I" part, not the "is there is any benefit" part.

Comment: @PeterCordes You've made good points here and thank you for the links. Edited.

Comment: Converting from Int64 to Int32 should usually be free, and (on x86-64) so should unsigned Int32 to any 64-bit integer.  Writing a 32-bit register in x86-64 zero-extends to 64-bit implicitly.  (I think AArch64 is the same, and AArch64 even has features to let you use a 32-bit integer as an array index without sign-extending it to pointer width.)  I haven't looked at Swift compiler output so IDK how good the compiler is at taking advantage of these HW features.

Comment: Fun fact: In C, the thing that lets compilers avoid redoing sign-extension of an `int32_t` array index in a loop is signed integer overflow being UB.  So they can promote it to 64-bit.  In languages without this, and sometimes even in C, yes you can write loops that compile with an extra sign-extension instruction (at least for x86-64; AArch64 has an addressing mode that sign extends an index which should help sometimes.)